# The representation of the array

Tags: arrays, c

If it is defined as follows:

```c
char x[] = "abcdefg";
char y[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
```

then why array `x` is not equivalent to array `y`?

Comment: Because the C compiler automatically adds the NUL terminator to the first, making it `char x[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'}; `

Comment: But if you explicitly provide the array length in the `[]`, these will become equivalent.

Comment: ...and `"abcdefg"` already includes a NUL terminator. It's a string literal which is copied to the array, and the array is automatically sized (if not stated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a manual array, you choose put or not the end character "\0", BUT when the C compiler read the second way to create the array, add automatically the end character, so it's different because have different length.

You can also test with the following example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(x));
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(y));
}
```

Comment: You can't pass `y` to `strlen()` because it's not a C string. I suggest `sizeof`. Moreover, `%d` is the wrong specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: True, my bad, it's fixed now